# Proving that a function is in $L^2(\Bbb{R}^2)$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that the function $(x,y)↦e^{-(xy−1)^2−y^2} \in L^2(\Bbb{R}^2)$. Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the substitution $z = xy $ (for $y \neq 0$). This yields 
$$
\int (f (x,y))^2 d (x,y) = \int \frac {e^{-2 [(z-1)^2 - y^2]}}{|y|} d (z,y)=\infty
$$
because of the singularity at $y=0$ (use Fubini's theorem.

Hence your claim is false.